# How to find all category with the help of attribute for menu purpose in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1.1

I need  category list with the help of attribute for creating custom menu visible in all pages.

I have created a drop-down category attribute. I would like to display all the categories for one on the values in the drop-down. Actually I want to display all the values but separately, that way I can create four columns of category listings.

I can display the attribute on the category page but i need to be able to echo the list on all the pages.

I have one parent category id

and attribute detail :

Attribute code:
[image]

attribute value

[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggw3u.png)

i want category list as per attribute id. Means which ***category*** product have attribute 0-3 Months,  will list

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code for that.

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('age',array('eq' => '0 - 3 Months'));//change value as per yours
    foreach($collection as $category){
        print_r($category->getData());
    }
```

If above code not work then try below code

```
$attr = 'age';
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$attr = $_category->getResource()->getAttribute($attr);
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
    $option_id = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId("0 - 3 Months");//change value as per yours
}

    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('age',array('eq' => $option_id));
    foreach($collection as $category){
        print_r($category->getData());
    }
```

Comment: thanks!
 Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in  app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816

Comment: its product attribute or category attribute?

Comment: check new answer  and if its not work tell me I will give you another solution

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function usesSource() on boolean in  app/design/frontend/ibees/default/template/page/html/header.phtml on line 344